# Qt - png images not displaying when deploy

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a simple GUI with Qt and I have 2 .png images (splash screen and a label) in the resources.
Inside Qt work normally but if I deploy it with "windeployqt" command it will not displaying the images.
For .png images don't need any .dll file. So I don't understood why they don't show?
Using: Qt 5.9 for windows

Edit:

In the main.cpp (Splash Screen):

```
QSplashScreen * splashScreen = new QSplashScreen;
splashScreen->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/7Guard.png"));
splashScreen->move((ScreenWidth/2)-(splashScreen->width()/2), (ScreenHeight/2)-(splashScreen->height()/2));
splashScreen->show();
QThread::msleep(3000);
splashScreen->close();
```

On my mainwindow.ui I selected the image from the proprieties of the label (pixmap).

All the images are in the Resources File:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>7Guard.png</file>
        <file>7Guard7.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Why do you say you do not need .dll for .png images?

Comment: did you add the images as "Qt Resource" (i.e. in a qrc file)?

Comment: Even if you have it loaded in the resource you need the .dll.

Comment: @Felix Yes, I add as "Qt Resources"

Comment: @eyllanesc I think don't need .dll for png images. I read somewhere that as built-in, for jpeg and another yes, when you make the deploy will show that .dll files.

Comment: @Samega7Cattac Can you show us a bit of your code? Like where you load the images.

Comment: @BenjaminT Ok, I will!

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609806/qt-png-images-not-showing-up-in-deployment-app