# Qt png images not showing up in deployment app

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, resources, png

My .png images show up im Qt Creator and also when i build my project in both debug and release situations. When I try to deploy my exe and run it my images don't show up.

My .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WinSim
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


RESOURCES += \
resourcefile.qrc
win32:RC_ICONS += icons\uokicon.ico
```

My resource file:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>icons/ico.png</file>
    <file>icons/ppicon.png</file>
    <file>icons/cricon.png</file>
    <file>icons/bgim.png</file>
    <file>icons/button.png</file>
    <file>icons/startmenu.png</file>
    <file>icons/power.png</file>
    <file>icons/uokicon.ico</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: could indicate which files are attached after the deployment, are you using windeployqt?

Comment: Im not using windeployqt. I just put the necessary dll's in a folder with the exe. That's how I've always done it and it works great.

Comment: And if it works very well because you think you have that error ?, it is not working. Qt is a complex library so it is advisable to use windeployqt to do the deployment, check: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: I'll try and i'll let you know if it works

Comment: God im so stupid haha. Thank you, it works !!

Comment: I'd say you missed a dll from the `platform` directory, I had the same problem when deploying an app to another computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QPixmap image loading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967115/qpixmap-image-loading-problem)

Answer (score 1):

All i needed to do was deploy my program with windeployqt. Thank you @eyllanesc for pointing that out !